# Migrating a program from VB2015 to VB2019 - program won't start

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I wrote a Visual Basic program back in VB4 (yes, really!) to track my petrol/gas consumption, and subsequently compiled it in VB6, Visual Studio Express 2010 (I think), VS Express 2015 for desktop, and I'm now trying to compile it in VS 2019 Community, without success.

I made a back-up copy of the source code folders, and pointed VB at the original .sln file.  The source all seemed to load up ok, but when I try to run the program in debug mode, the splash screen comes up, but never goes away, and the main form "frmMain" never gets loaded. I set a breakpoint at the first line of code in frmMain:

```
Private Sub FrmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
```

but I get an error "The breakpoint will never be hit.  No symbols have been loaded for the current document".

This doesn't mean anything to me, and this message has appeared in the forums for years, seeking explanation, without an agreed common solution.  I'm definitely in 'Debug' mode, not 'Release'.  I've checked in Properties/Application that frmMain is the Startup form, and the Splash screen is set to frmSplash. Is the 'current document' frmMain?  What are 'Symbols'?

Incidentally, I have a lot of 'Messages' which say, eg 'Message IDE1006 Naming rule violation: These words must begin with upper case characters: btnSaveNewCar_Click'.  Why is this?  It's never arisen before - has something changed in VB?

Comment: It is a proven fact that large blocks of text are hard to read and breaking such blocks into paragraphs makes them easier to read. You should strive to make your question as easy to read as possible, thus helping us to help you.

Comment: After the *migration*, what .Net version are you targeting? Have you checked, in the starting Project Properties, whether the `ApplicationFramework` is enabled and what is the startup Form (in .Net 5, it should be `Sub Main`) -- Those messages, as `IDE1006`, are set in the IDE through the `Options` tool. You can set up the IDE as you prefer (better keep some standard naming conventions enabled. This one, related to the naming of event handlers is not part of this standard, you can simply disable that notification).

Comment: `Symbols` is debug symbols (a .pdb file). Please ensure that symbols generation is enabled for project. E.g. via top menu: project -> {application} Properties -> Compile -> Advanced Compile Options ... -> ensure that 'Generate debug info' is set to `full`. Then after building the project in the output folder there should be `.pdb` file(s)

Comment: you could not have opened + used nor worked on a VB4 application with vs 2015. Unless you re-wrote parts and converted the application to run/work with vb.net then your "memory" is a quite wrong. Now if  you really did re-write the application and make it work in v2015? Then it will and should and can open in vs 2019 without any issues at a all. I suspect your machine had VB6 installed 6 years ago when you played or worked on this in 2015 -but you were not and could not have been using Visual Studio 2015 - you were likely using VB6.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, all.  It's a bit wordy, as the program has had a convoluted history.  Answers:

Comment: Thanks for your comments all, especially Renat.  Debug info is already set to full, and there IS a pdb file in the output Debug folder.  But (and this is embarrassing) I also spotted that there was an .exe file in the Debug folder as well - so it HAS compiled.  When I fired it up it generated a tracing messagebox which previously was hidden behind the IDE window – so I never saw it until now.  How embarrassing.  Apologies for wasting all your valuable time.  If I could, I’d buy you all a beer!

Comment: The naming rules are advisory only and may be freely ignored.